# how to Login to website programatically using using C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to login to this website using C#: 
Here is my attempt but its sending me to first page. Not returning me the next page, that should be visible after login, please help me to resolve this:

```
string formParams = 
string.Format("mail={0}&password={1}", store@admin.com", "admin");
      string cookieHeader;
      WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://muslimgowns.com/dashboard/login/public_login");
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
            using (StreamReader sr = new  StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                File.AppendAllText("first.txt", pageSource);
            }

            string pageSource1;
            string getUrl = "http://muslimgowns.com/dashboard/home";
            WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
            getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
            WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSource1 = sr.ReadToEnd();
                File.AppendAllText("second.txt", pageSource1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking question. What have you tried ? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the generic way to do that (the most general lets say) is to make a programmatic http request with the login data and keep state in your script (cookies etc) so session is maintained and script is like a logged-in user.  however this depends on what you want to do and how the site is accessed

Comment: Okay, here is my code but its sending me to first page. Not returning me the next page, that should be visible after login:

Answer (score 4):

You can use Selenium WebDriver to automate the login process or any other process for that matter.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/

The basic idea is to:
1. Include Selenium Webdriver in your C# project
2. Goto to www.fastundercar.com

```
driver.Url = "http://www.fastundercar.com";
```

3. Find the Username, Password fields and the submit button (by Id, name or class) e.g.

   IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("ULogin$txtUserName"));
4. Set values for the username and password fields
5. Submit the button -

   driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

Check out the below link for reference:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Firefox has a nice Add-on FireBug along with an Add-on-add-on FirePath. This gives you an easy way to find ids/xpaths of page objects.